# Impossible to use injection with DWR

Tags: jsf, dwr

i have tow beans and i inject the second in the the first but when i call a method from the seconde insid the first , dwr doesn't khnow it, this is my code of tow beans and dwr.xml

this is dwr.xml :

```
<dwr>
 <allow>
 <create creator="new" javascript="Hello">
 <param name="class" value="eu.sorinzo.lc.Hello"/>
 </create>
 </allow>
</dwr>
```

Bean hello

```
package eu.sorinzo.lc;
import eu.sorinzo.lc.common.HelloYou;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Hello implements Serializable{ 
@Inject
private HelloYou helloYou;
public String sayMyHello() {
return helloYou.MyHelloYou();
 }}
```

Bean helloYou

```
package eu.sorinzo.lc.common;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class HelloYou implements Serializable{
public String MyHelloYou(){
return "success MyHelloYou";
 }}
```

if the the method sayMyHello of Hello bean returns a simple message , when i call it , it works good but if it returns the message of MyHelloYou() it gives a error message:

```
console.trace(): engine.js:789
dwr.engine._debug() engine.js:789
dwr.engine._debug() engine.js:789
dwr.engine.defaultErrorHandler() engine.js:180
dwr.engine.remote.handleException() engine.js:921
<anonyme> engine.js line 584 > eval:6
<anonyme> engine.js line 584 > eval:2
dwr.engine._eval() engine.js:584
dwr.engine.transport.xhr.stateChange() engine.js:1632
dwr.engine.transport.xhr.send/batch.req.onreadystatechange() engine.js:1477
"Error: undefined, Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dwr.xml you can use just :

**new**: Which uses the Java 'new' operator.

**static**: Which uses the 'getInstance()' method (by default) to obtain an instance of the class.

**none**: This does not create objects. See below for why. (v1.1+)

**scripted**: Uses a scripting language like BeanShell or Groovy via BSF.

**spring**: Gives access to beans through the Spring Framework.

**jsf**: Uses objects from JSF. (v1.1+)

**struts**: Uses struts FormBeans. (v1.1+)

**pageflow**: Gives access to a PageFlow from Beehive or Weblogic. (v1.1+)

I think that DWR doesn't support injection if you work with JEE6 CDI and it works juste with the creators type written before